# Why can't I use the << operator with the value extracted from this variables_map?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I'm familiarizing myself with `boost::program_options` (and C++ in general).  I wrote the function below, but I can't quite understand the error I'm getting.  Here's the code (note that `po` is an alias for `boost::program_options`).

```
int application(po::variables_map& vm)
{
    std::cout << &vm << std::endl;
    std::cout << vm["infile"];

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The error I'm receiving is for the second line in the function body.  It reads: `"no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const boost::program_options::variable_value’)"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is actually pretty straightforward for once: there’s no overload for `<<` which works with `program_options::variable_value`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, right... how would I cout the contents of the variable_value type, then?  Surely there must be a way to access the std::string I put in there.

Comment: I don’t think there is – nor that there should be. `variable_value` is an opaque type that can hold any kind of value, and the only operation it supports is retrieving that value and storing it somewhere else, with the correct type. That’s it. *If you know the type* then you can retrieve it via `as`: `std::cout << vm["infile"].as<std::string>();`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Apologies if I was unclear!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout << vm["infile"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
```

This only works if you know the underlying type. It uses `boost::any` and `boost::any_cast` in the implementation. If the value is not a string in the above example, it will throw a `boost::bad_any_cast` exception.

If there are only few possible types, you can chain try/catch or use typeid to discover what the correct type is. That would be super hacky of course. :)